# Fix two buttons (left and right) to bottom of dynamic container that works responsively

Tags: css

I need to force two buttons to the bottom of a container, floating one left and one right.

The caveats however are:-

- The length of the content in the container may differ.
- The width of the containers can not be fixed.

This needs to work responsively so at any device-width, the two buttons needs to retain a bottom-left and bottom-right, in proportion to all other elements effect.

```css
.left {float: left;}
.right {float: right;}

.service-blocks {margin: 20px 0;}

.service-blocks ul {margin: 0 auto;}

.service-blocks li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 29.4%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #222;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 1%;
  min-height: 350px;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

.service-blocks li:first-of-type {margin-left: 0;}
.service-blocks li:nth-of-type(3) {margin-right: 0;}

.service-blocks li .button-container {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.service-blocks li a.button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.25;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.service-blocks li a.button.enquire {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    border-color: #5cb85c;
}

.service-blocks li a.button.learn {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #384C6A;
    border-color: #384C6A;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-blocks">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2>Service 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sollicitudin, ligula quis convallis accumsan, ipsum ex lobortis risus, a malesuada orci turpis vel leo. Fusce sit amet arcu est. Ut mi nunc, vestibulum eu urna sed, blandit euismod est. Aliquam ut gravida orci. Sed varius iaculis diam, efficitur rutrum massa blandit sed. Nam in odio ornare, fringilla ex in, dapibus tortor. Aliquam aliquet ac dui sit amet fermentum.</p>
      <span class="button-container">
        <a href="/contact-us/" class="button left enquire" target="_blank">Enquire</a>
        <a href="/service-1/" class="button right learn">Learn More</a>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Service 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sollicitudin, ligula quis convallis accumsan, ipsum ex lobortis risus, a malesuada orci turpis vel leo. Fusce sit amet arcu est. Ut mi nunc, vestibulum eu urna sed, blandit euismod est. Aliquam ut gravida orci. Sed varius iaculis diam, efficitur rutrum massa blandit sed. Nam in odio ornare, fringilla ex in, dapibus tortor. Aliquam aliquet ac dui sit amet fermentum.</p>
      <span class="button-container">
        <a href="/contact-us/" class="button left enquire" target="_blank">Enquire</a>
        <a href="/service-2/" class="button right learn">Learn More</a>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Service 3</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sollicitudin, ligula quis convallis accumsan, ipsum ex lobortis risus, a malesuada orci turpis vel leo. Fusce sit amet arcu est. Ut mi nunc, vestibulum eu urna sed, blandit euismod est. Aliquam ut gravida orci. Sed varius iaculis diam, efficitur rutrum massa blandit sed. Nam in odio ornare, fringilla ex in, dapibus tortor. Aliquam aliquet ac dui sit amet fermentum.</p>
      <span class="button-container">
        <a href="/contact-us/" class="button left enquire" target="_blank">Enquire</a>
        <a href="/service-3/" class="button right learn">Learn More</a>
      </span>
    </li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have created a basic demo here too in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zigojacko/m3mbdL4s/11/).

I have fiddled around with various relative -> absolute positioning, if I apply a width to `.button-container` then I can make the buttons float left and right but this seems rather clunky responsively, whether different px widths at different media queries or trying to a one-size-fits-all with a % width.

I'd prefer to keep this CSS only if possible but will consider jQuery if absolutely necessary.

Comment: What about `position: absolute;` ??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m3mbdL4s/13/

Comment: @AnzilkhaN - Yes, can use `position: absolute` if need be. Already am on the button container.

Comment: @yjs The buttons are not fixed to the bottom in your jsfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m3mbdL4s/20/

Comment: @yjs remove the 94% width on `.button-container` which does not retain consistency responsively and then the floats break. I said that in my question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m3mbdL4s/28/
Actually 94% does not break, it was li 33% breaked...sorry...reverted it and fixed. plz chk once...

Comment: You're not understanding @yjs - I can't have and don't want a 94% width on the button container if I can help it - it does not work perfectly responsively - it would mean I would have to add lots of different width breakpoints for this element specifically which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m3mbdL4s/32/

Comment: It's not bad @yjs but the `margin-bottom: 23%` you have added is always going to be effective from the end of the `<p>` and I said in my question that the length of the content could be different in length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use flex method and resize the button size according to container.

css:

```
.service-blocks li .button-container {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: I had played around with flex positioning too but to no avail. I tried your suggestion but that [hasn't done the trick](https://jsfiddle.net/zigojacko/fonsork8/2/) neither.

Comment: Almost @Raj - how to force them now to the bottom of the container or by 10px to match the padding?

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/raj_mutant/fonsork8/33/    using position:absolute this is moved to bottom

Comment: Thank you @Raj - I have used what you provided with an [a slight extension](https://jsfiddle.net/zigojacko/m3mbdL4s/35/) applying left and right margin to the buttons and a bottom margin on the button container to achieve what seems to work perfectly responsively.

Answer (score 2):

After setting the button container to absolute width will be set to auto to make container for available make use of left and right position properties.And then set the button positions to left ,right ,bottom 0px respectively.

Please check the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3mbdL4s/44/)

```css
.left {float: left;}
.right {float: right;}

.service-blocks {margin: 20px 0;}
.service-blocks p {width:225px}

.service-blocks ul {margin: 0 auto;}

.service-blocks li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 43.05%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #222;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 1%;
  min-height: 350px;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

.service-blocks li:first-of-type {margin-left: 0;}
.service-blocks li:nth-of-type(3) {margin-right: 0;}

.service-blocks li .button-container {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
}

.service-blocks li a.button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.25;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.service-blocks li a.button.enquire {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    border-color: #5cb85c;
    left:0px;
}

.service-blocks li a.button.learn {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #384C6A;
    border-color: #384C6A;
    right:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-blocks">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2>Service 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sollicitudin, ligula quis convallis accumsan, ipsum ex lobortis risus, a malesuada orci turpis vel leo. Fusce sit amet arcu est. Ut mi nunc, vestibulum eu urna sed, blandit euismod est. Aliquam ut gravida orci. Sed varius iaculis diam, efficitur rutrum massa blandit sed. Nam in odio ornare, fringilla ex in, dapibus tortor. Aliquam aliquet ac dui sit amet fermentum.</p>
      <span class="button-container">
        <a href="/contact-us/" class="button left enquire" target="_blank">Enquire</a>
        <a href="/service-1/" class="button right learn">Learn More</a>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Service 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sollicitudin, ligula quis convallis accumsan, ipsum ex lobortis risus, a malesuada orci turpis vel leo. Fusce sit amet arcu est. Ut mi nunc, vestibulum eu urna sed, blandit euismod est. Aliquam ut gravida orci. Sed varius iaculis diam, efficitur rutrum massa blandit sed. Nam in odio ornare, fringilla ex in, dapibus tortor. Aliquam aliquet ac dui sit amet fermentum.</p>
      <span class="button-container">
        <a href="/contact-us/" class="button left enquire" target="_blank">Enquire</a>
        <a href="/service-2/" class="button right learn">Learn More</a>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Service 3</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sollicitudin, ligula quis convallis accumsan, ipsum ex lobortis risus, a malesuada orci turpis vel leo. Fusce sit amet arcu est. Ut mi nunc, vestibulum eu urna sed, blandit euismod est. Aliquam ut gravida orci. Sed varius iaculis diam, efficitur rutrum massa blandit sed. Nam in odio ornare, fringilla ex in, dapibus tortor. Aliquam aliquet ac dui sit amet fermentum.</p>
      <span class="button-container">
        <a href="/contact-us/" class="button left enquire" target="_blank">Enquire</a>
        <a href="/service-3/" class="button right learn">Learn More</a>
      </span>
    </li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```